# Multi Param URL redirect issue in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a bit of an issue I cannot seem to get around.

On a WordPress install we have these special profile pages that were triggered by a URL structure such as this

**/our-firm/profile/1/Some.Name**

They wanted the name appended to the URL so the URL's were prettier. This looks like it was previously managed through some type of plugin before we got it. Now a recent WordPress update has corrupted that plugin, and this functionality no longer works. I have it where it at least works if you do not use the name, example:

**/our-firm/profile/1/**

But that of course is not what the client wants. I have attempted to remedy the issue with some .htaccess rewriting that follows:

```
RewriteRule ^our-firm/profile/([0-9]+)/([^+]+)?$ our-firm/profile?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

But I am not getting anywhere with it. What weirder is, and it may just be something I am over looking, but if I visit:

**/our-firm/profile?id=1&profile_name=Some.Name**

That even works fine.

Any help would be great on this. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use add_rewrite_rule of WP (http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Example:

```
function wptuts_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^path-1/([^/]*)?$','index.php?page_id=PAGE_ID&nameSurname=$matches[1]','top');
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'wptuts_add_rewrite_rules' );

function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "nameSurname"; 
    return $aVars;
}

add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

and You get the params in the page using $wp_query->query_vars["nameSurname"];